# "Hi, Joe," versus "Hi Joe,"

Tags: commas, salutations

The salutation "hi, Joe," often does not have a comma after "hi." "Hi" is not a modifier like "dear." It is not part of a person's title. "Hi" is an interjection and is normally set off with commas. If one would put a comma after "good morning" in "good morning, Joe," then why is the comma after "hi" omitted so often? Is it proper to omit this comma?

Comment: I think that because "*Hi*" is informal by definition, whether a comma is used or not probably doesn't matter.  What really matters is whether the meaning is conveyed properly and in this case I'm sure nobody would ever get confused whether a comma was used or not.

Comment: Hi Anthony. Commas separate complex ideas for clarity. There isn't much complexity in Hi Joe :-)

Comment: But commas are also used to signal non-verbal communication. The comma here connotes considered, extended (or distracted?!) greeting; its omission connotes briskness or even brusqueness.